# Mounting USB subdirectory for NFS export

Tags: mount, nfs

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

I am having trouble exporting a directory from a USB drive. I have a number of exports similarly configured as to permissions and they are just fine.

Here is the error:

```
mount --bind /mnt/usb2T/inbox /export/inbox
mount: /export/inbox: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.
```

And here are the directories involved in the issue:

The USB drive:

```
ls -la /mnt/
drwxrwxr-x  7 root users 4096 Sep 14 14:29 usb2T
```

successfully mounted to export as

```
/mnt/usb2T /export/usb2T nfs bind 0 0
```

and successfully exported and mounted by clients as

```
/export/usb2T 10.0.0.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

However when I try the same approach with a subdirectory of usb2T, I get into trouble:

```
ls -la /mnt/usb2T/inbox | wc -l
96
```

So it does exist and there are files there.

And so does the /export/inbox directory:

```
ls -la /export
drwxrwxr-x  0 root users    0 Sep 14 14:29 inbox
drwxrwxr-x  7 root users 4096 Sep 14 14:29 usb2T
```

Bind mount is attempted with this line in fstab:

```
/mnt/usb2T/inbox /export/inbox nfs bind 0 0
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS is new enough to use `systemd`, and `systemd` does not mount the filesystems listed in `/etc/fstab` with just a traditional `mount -a`.

Instead, it auto-generates a `.mount`-type *systemd unit file* for each `/etc/fstab` line, adds some default dependencies to those units, and then runs those units in parallel at boot time, basically as soon as possible.

The trick is, unless `systemd` is explicitly told that one mount depends on another being already done, there is no guarantee of any particular order. The ordering of `/etc/fstab` lines has no meaning, like it once might have had with `mount -a`.

Your second bind mount can only succeed if `/mnt/usb2T` is already mounted. To tell this requirement to `systemd`, you'll need to change its `fstab` line to this:

```
/mnt/usb2T/inbox /export/inbox nfs bind,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/usb2T 0 0
```

Or, depending on `systemd` version used, to this:

```
/mnt/usb2T/inbox /export/inbox nfs bind,x-systemd.requires-mounts-for=/mnt/usb2T 0 0
```

(Technically, on bind mounts, the filesystem type in the `fstab` line should probably be `none` instead of `nfs`, but I think that's ignored with bind mounts anyway.)